# Problem in cube's dimensions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I've got the following question.

I have 3 dimensions:
Dim1
Dim2
Dim3

And a fact table, let's say:
FACT

After processing the cube, I run a query which is to obtain the values filtered by dimension Dim1. However, I only get values for one member of Dim1

```
select [Measures].[Volume] on columns,
[Dim1].[ID].[ID].members on rows
from [Cube]

Dim1ID  | Volume
  A     |  10
  B     | (NULL)
  C     | (NULL)
```

But when I run the following SQL:

```
select d.id, f.volume
from fact f, dim1 d
where d.id=f.id

Dim1ID  | Value
  A     |  10
  B     |  20
  C     |  30
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

When processing the cubes do you have any errors or warnings?  If there are attribute key errors some of the fact rows may be ignored or converted to Unknown member. If that happens your data warehouse won't agree with your cube results.

An attribute key error is when a fact has a key value that is not in the dimension.  This applies to ALL dimensions so you may have all keys correct for dim1 but if you have facts relating to keys not in Dim2 and Dim3 then the fact row will drop out.

Depending on your error configuration even if you have Errors and Warnings reporting problems the Process can still report success.  In the Process Progress window in Visual Studio check for "Red" rows when it's processing a measure group and drill down on these to find the source of the error.

Comment: I Craig, thanks for you reply. I don't have errors in my cube. But I think my problem is that all the keys of the dimensions isn't primary keys in facts table. What do you think?